# Automatically Update the custom check box field based on Owner/ Owner profile and permission set

Tags: profile, customsetting, user, field-update, permission-sets

For new account, automatically Update the custom check-box field to true for User-xx or Account Owner profile-xx and permission set-xx.

Need to implement this Without Code. By using custom settings, how can we achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify your question?  Would this be an "on create" check, to determine if the current user has specific profile, and if so markthe checkbox to True?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow wherein the entry criteria can check if user has required profile of permission; In action you can check the checkbox.

Custom settings will not be usable without using apex code. However, you can use custom labels, if you want to make values configurable.

Comment: Can you make a workflow rule evaluate a permission-set assignment?  I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: Not permission set, but you can create a custom permission (which I would suggest is a better solution). You can assign custom permission to required profiles/ permission set. This will help you to ensure that you are not hard-binding your workflow with profile/ permission set

Comment: @Murali: Is your query resolved?